# Compose : scaffold unnecessary systemBar padding due to `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

working on an edge2edge display app, i came across a situation about `scaffold`, according to the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material), the scaffold padding values are used to offset the top and bottom bars, **if they exist**. Turns out that when i use scaffold without providing top/bottom parameter, the contents of the scaffold are padded at the top & bottom automatically with blank space

If i provide a parameter for either the `topBar` or `bottomBar`, the other gets automatically filled with blank space.

**Catch :** This only happens when `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` is used

**Code Snippet:**

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) //commenting this line of code gives desired results but defeates the E2E display

    setContent {
        TestTheme {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Cyan)
            ) {
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(0.8f)
                        .align(Alignment.Center),

                    ) { paddingValues ->

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(paddingValues)
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(Color.White)
                    ) {

                        Log.d("scaffold", "padding values = $paddingValues")

                        Text("Android")
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**not commented :**                ------                      **commented :**

[image: not commented] -----  [image: commented]

**Q :** Pls, what is the reason for this behaviour, & how can i achieve a working E2E with the scaffold not adding the unnecessary paddings?

**Developing tools :**

Lastest Android Studio(Electric Eel)

androidx.compose.material3

Answer (score 6):

## There are two options:

1. Don't use Scaffold's paddingValues

---

2. Set zero contentWindowInsets to Scaffold like this:

   ```
    Scaffold(
        contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp), 
        ...
    ) {
        //Your content
    }
   ```

The default value is `ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets`, which consists of `WindowInsets.systemBars`

This approach is also used by [Google's developers](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/553f55f9786209495d4afbcd2d39d167a828050c/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/ui/NiaApp.kt#L133)

Comment: Works perfectly even with or without AppBar or BottomBar :)

Answer (score 1):

Bug report it in accompanist system ui repo https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues . And there is also a issue with inset-ui scafold padding which is not working with dark theme properly using version 30.1.